# Count records against filters

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have following 4 tables in sql with some records in them.

```
Users

UserId  UserName  EmploymentId
------  --------  -------------
1       User1      1          
2       John       1          
3       Doe        2
```

---

```
Country

CountryId  countryName  
------     --------  
1          USA                
2          UK
```

---

```
EmpStatus

EmploymentId  EmpName  
------        --------  
1             Employed                
2             Un-Employed
```

---

```
UserNationality (many to many )

UserId  CountryId
------  --------  
1          1          
1          1          
3          1
```

---

Now what I am trying to achieve is get show counts with filter criteria.i.e. I have view which should display filter criteria as shown below.

```
**Search Records**

Search by country

USA (3)
UK  (0)

Search by employment

Employed (2)
Un-Employed (1)
```

Note that in `UserNationality` table there is a many to many relation ship between `UserId` and `CountryId`. So there may or may not be a record against a user.

I've tried counting by applying joins on the tables but it doesn't give desired results.

Also tried to used `PARTITION` but I've so far failed to generate the results. What approach should I use to solve this issue ?

Comment: Same user has more than one nationality?

Comment: Yes they can have 0-* nationalities..

Comment: Multiple CASE ... COUNT() statements could work, but it would get messy

Comment: hmm.. actually there are lot more then just 4 tables.. with many cases involved .. so yes it will get a but messy..

Comment: Please provide code which you use as you said 'I've tried counting by applying joins on the tables'. How exactly you've tried?